# PHP - How can I do my own human verification?

Tags: php, captcha

I'd like to make my own php script for the human verification . Like an easy series of numbers/letters (captcha), nothing special.

Suggestion? Tips? Things to keep in mind?

Comment: An example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/milyen-nap-van-most/

Comment: Why? What's different about your case that makes standard solutions unfit?

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that selfmade captchas seldomly provide the OCR resistance of complex solutions (whirly google captchas). They are sufficient only for small sites and for a while, so acceptable for learning to implement such a feature.

Comment: Smashing Magazine recently did a fantastic article on capatchas: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this issue is widely covered by a simple google search.

you can use [this](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/create_captcha_protection.php) tutorial example for a reference:

Answer (score 4):

You could use a captcha service such as recaptcha to check for a human.

Or create your own using an image library and storing the answers in a database and giving the names of the image file something that cannot be traced back to the word, you might need to make the words fuzzy as bot can use ocr.

another novel approach i saw was someone using an ascii art captcha like this

http://www.network-science.de/ascii/

Comment: And Recaptcha does not only work but also helps to digitize books at the same time. Makes more sense and is better than a selfwritten thing

Answer (score 2):

I keep a list of questions and their associated answer server side. When generating the HTML for a form with a question I add the randomly selected question to the form and store the index of the question (from the list of questions) in the user's session. Then, when answer is posted I can simply check the answer with the index from the session.

Worth baring in mind that:

- questions should be easy should be
- unambiguous and have only one
- possible answer user can enter answer in any case

Also worth having a "why are we asking this?" bit on the form as some users may be a bit confused as to why the question is there.

Comment: In fact this could be a greater solution than captcha : I just hear about "OCS" and those troubles.... I don't think list of question could be cracked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GD library to accomplish this. An example of how it can be done here: http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/simple-php-gd-capcha-image/